# How to write iMacros scripts in javascript using scripting interface and call those from batch files

Tags: javascript, batch-file, imacros

Sorry this is a relatively simple question, but there's some confusion between the firefox javascript scripting interface and the scripting interface that comes with the enterprise version of iMacros.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Make a javascript file which utilizes the enterprise version of iMacros' scripting interface. Not the one bundled with the firefox version.
2. Be able to use any browser via that scripting interface. This means using iimOpen("-fx") for firefox, -ie for IE, -cr for chrome, etc, using the command reference found [here](http://wiki.imacros.net/Command_Reference#Scripting_Interface_Command_Overview)
3. Be able to call that javascript file from a .bat file so that I can automate it with Windows Task Scheduler

I've searched around a lot, and most questions are related to the firefox-specific scripting interface and are only for javascript/one browser. The few that are using the enterprise scripting interface don't have good answers/examples. I basically just want to have the shell of what I need to get started so that I can just start writing the actual script with iimPlayCode() calls. I'm new to javascript for scripting purposes, and most things I've done are using projects such as visual studio solutions, so I'm used to imports and such. For example, what do I need to define so that the script knows how to interpret iMacros commands? Usually that would be an import, but do I need an import for a script or is that built in somehow? Do I need a main or something similar? etc

There's [this example](http://wiki.imacros.net/JavaScript) on the iMacros wiki, but it's built like an html file that you have to click to start, and I don't think that'd work well with a batch file for scheduling. As far as I know, that's the only javascript example using the enterprise scripting interface.

System information:

Windows 10

iMacros 11.1 Enterprise

Latest Firefox/Chrome/IE

Comment: I think you should ask this directly on their support forum. There aren't too many around here who use the paid version. In fact I don't even remember the last time anybody asked a question about automating Windows tasks with iMacros

Comment: I have asked there as well, but I was told there was more of a community of javascript users on stackoverflow.